# Shortest route between multiple points in mapkit for iphone app

Tags: iphone, mapkit, shortest-path

In my application suppose user selects 4 cities to vist with S as starting city and D as destination city then is there any API or webservice for this .

Here the users visits the city one time only and  the output should be the shortest path   between A and D by covering all the cities. If somebody has any other idea it is also welcomed.

Thanks and Regards
Mrugen

Comment: This is commonly known as the Traveling Salesman problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem Except the TSP does not specify a start and end point.

Comment: @ kjetil i know its related t travelling salesman problem but i wanted to know is there any API for it or any webservice available for this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapquest has recently really taken the lead in terms of navigation and geocoding APIs. FAR better than Google's offering, IMO. They're hosting OpenStreetMap data and an excellent (and wide open) interface to it. No access keys, no restrictions, just bang, DATA.

Here's the URL to their directions API. Short version is, provide two lat/lng points (which they also have an interface to look up from a street address or other landmark) and it'll give turn by turn directions.

http://open.mapquestapi.com/directions/

Comment: its currently closed. http://devblog.mapquest.com/2015/05/01/looking-for-a-free-open-appkey-read-this/

Answer (score 0):

firstly u should konw city"s latitude and longtitude
and u  use code

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D start = {43.759063, -79.236128};

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=%@,%@&saddr=%f,%f",mi.memberyLat,mi.memberLong,start.latitude  ,start.longitude];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: urlString]];
```

in this code 
mi.memberyLat means u pass city latitude 
mi.memberLong means u pass city long.

Comment: No i am looking for multiple location single optimum path .I think yuo didnt got my question.